# Hierarchical references abstraction with strict model

Tags: sql-server, database-design, referential-integrity

I want to abstract a real world hierarchy in a strict DB model (as strict as possible).

My problem is to to create a structure with a this-or-this-but-not-both rules set.

I have two entity types,

- *Device*, should be connectable to one other "device" as child and as parent.
- *Combiner*, it can be connected with multiple "devices" as parents and one as child.

BUT(!) a device can only be connected to one of them at the same time. So like "device" as only one child and one parent.

I try to visualize it somehow:

[image: pattern]

All my ideas are not strict but I searching if there is a pattern to solve this without rules on application level. On a class model I would solve this with inheritance. Some ideas?

Comment: Steffen, I got a comment on my answer for you.  There was an inappropriate use of an `UNIQUE Constraint` that needs to be swapped out for a `UNIQUE INDEX`.  Just wanted to make sure you knew that piece was wrong in case it had not been handled on your own already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.  Navigating the structure from top to bottom may be a little gross but maybe the app side objects can handle it.

I think you can build this out using 2 tables `dbo.Device` and `dbo.Combiner`.  Each table has a column that references who its parent object is, regardless of whether it is a `device` or a `combiner`.  We can then use a couple different types of `constraints` and a couple of `triggers` to ensure that the data follows the path you are looking to use.

***Table Structures*** (now your objects probably have more data points than just a `name` but for the sake of simplicity I am only going to keep track of a `name`)

***`dbo.Device`***

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Device
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name VarChar(100) NOT NULL,
    ParentDeviceID INT NULL,
    ParentCombinerID INT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Device] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_UniqueParentDeviceIDDevice 
ON dbo.Device(ParentDeviceID)  
WHERE ParentDeviceID IS NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Device]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Device_Device] FOREIGN KEY([ParentDeviceID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Device] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Device]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Combiner_Device] FOREIGN KEY([ParentCombinerID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Combiner] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Device]
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Device CHECK (ParentDeviceID IS NULL OR ParentCombinerID IS NULL)
GO
```

***`dbo.Combiner`***

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Combiner
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name VarChar(100) NOT NULL,
    ParentDeviceID INT NULL,
    ParentCombinerID INT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Combiner] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_UniqueParentDeviceIDCombiner
ON dbo.Combiner(ParentDeviceID)  
WHERE ParentDeviceID IS NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Combiner]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Combiner_Device] FOREIGN KEY([ParentDeviceID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Device] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Combiner]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Combiner_Combiner] FOREIGN KEY([ParentCombinerID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Combiner] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Combiner]
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Combiner CHECK (ParentDeviceID IS NULL OR ParentCombinerID IS NULL)
GO
```

Each table holds who its parent object is via `ParentDeviceID` or `ParentCombinerID`. The `Unique Filtered Index` on `ParentDeviceID` helps ensure that a given `Device` can only be the parent of one object (A `Unique Constraint` would stop multiple rows with a `NULL` value).  It isn't guaranteed so that is why we are going to use some triggers down the road.  The two `CHECK Constraint`s help ensure that any given object can only have 1 parent object instead of having both a `Device` and `Combiner` as a parent. The `Foreign Key`s ensure that the values stored in `ParentDeviceID` and `ParentCombinerID` are valid values for those two tables.

***`Trigger`s***

We can insert a `Trigger` on each `table`.  These `Trigger`s need to ensure:

1. On the `insert`/`update` of a `dbo.Device` record a value stored on `ParentDeviceID` is not already on `dbo.Combiner.ParentDeviceID`
2. On the `Insert`/`Update` of a `dbo.Combiner` record a value stored on `ParentDeviceID` is not already on `dbo.Device.ParentDeviceID`

```
-- On the Insert/Update of a dbo.Combiner record a value stored on ParentDeviceID is not already on dbo.Device.ParentDeviceID
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.CombinerCheck ON dbo.Combiner
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM INSERTED I
            INNER JOIN Device D
                ON I.ParentDeviceID = D.ParentDeviceID
    )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('This Combiner cannot be added since it''s parent Device is already a parent to a different Device.', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; --stops the Insert/Update
        RETURN 
    END
END

--On the insert/update of a dbo.Device record a value stored on ParentDeviceID is not already on dbo.Combiner.ParentDeviceID
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.DeviceCheck ON dbo.Device
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM INSERTED I
            INNER JOIN Combiner C
                ON I.ParentDeviceID = C.ParentDeviceID
    )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('This Device cannot be added since it''s parent Device is already a parent to a Combiner.', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; --stops the Insert/Update
        RETURN
    END
END
```

As an alternative this StackOverflow question apperently give the same or similar effect with a `Unique Index` on a `View`.  If you want to avoid `Triggers` than this may be a solution for you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314372/ms-sql-server-cross-table-constraint. I am not familiar with this approach but maybe it is a better solution for you.

***Examples***

Implementing the 1st Example provided (just 3 devices in a chain) would look something like this.  Just 3 records in `dbo.Device`:

```
+----+------+----------------+------------------+
| ID | Name | ParentDeviceID | ParentCombinerID |
+----+------+----------------+------------------+
|  1 | D1   | NULL           | NULL             |
|  2 | D2   | 1              | NULL             |
|  3 | D3   | 2              | NULL             |
+----+------+----------------+------------------+
```

Implementing the 2nd Example provided (1 Device --> 1 Combiner --> 3 Devices) would look something like this.  4 Records in `dbo.Device` and 1 Record in `dbo.Combiner`.

```
Device
+----+------+----------------+------------------+
| ID | Name | ParentDeviceID | ParentCombinerID |
+----+------+----------------+------------------+
|  1 | D1   | NULL           | NULL             |
|  2 | D2   | NULL           | 1                |
|  3 | D3   | NULL           | 1                |
|  4 | D4   | NULL           | 1                |
+----+------+----------------+------------------+

Combiner
+----+------+----------------+------------------+
| ID | Name | ParentDeviceID | ParentCombinerID |
+----+------+----------------+------------------+
|  1 | C1   |              1 | NULL             |
+----+------+----------------+------------------+
```

One more, slightly more complicated example to display all the relationship options:
[image: Slightly More Involved Example]

```
dbo.Device
+----+------+----------------+------------------+
| ID | Name | ParentDeviceID | ParentCombinerID |
+----+------+----------------+------------------+
|  1 | D1   | NULL           | NULL             |
|  2 | D2   | 1              | NULL             |
|  3 | D3   | NULL           | 1                |
|  4 | D4   | NULL           | 1                |
|  5 | D5   | NULL           | 1                |
|  6 | D6   | NULL           | 2                |
|  7 | D7   | NULL           | 2                |
|  8 | D8   | NULL           | 2                |
+----+------+----------------+------------------+

dbo.Combiner
+----+------+----------------+------------------+
| ID | Name | ParentDeviceID | ParentCombinerID |
+----+------+----------------+------------------+
|  1 | C1   | 2              | NULL             |
|  2 | C2   | NULL           | 1                |
+----+------+----------------+------------------+
```

Hopefully this give you all you need from the database side.  Again I think this will be complicated on the App side navigating the table structures.  But the database should keep the relationships the way you want to.

Comment: Wouldn’t the `UNIQUE` constraint on ParentDeviceID prevent more than one NULL in that column? I think it would need to be a unique filtered index.

Comment: @JohnRees You are totally right, I assumed `UNIQUE` ignored `NULL` values.  Thank you for catching that.  I will update the answer.